# 他プロセスのEdge起動コマンドをトリガーとして、リモートデバッグ状態で起動したい

Tags: windows, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

他プロセスでEdgeを単純に起動する機能がありますが、そのEdgeを自動操作したいと考えています。
自動操作するには主に(1)DOM操作による方法と(2)WebDriver経由による方法がありますが、(2)のWebDriver経由を採用するつもりです。
しかし、そのためにはEdgeをリモートデバッグ状態 "edge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222"等で起動しなければならないですが、他プロセスのためコマンドの引数を操作することができません。
Edgeの起動をトリガーにして引数を埋め込んだり、あるいは他プロセスの子プロセスとして任意のedgeコマンドを入力することは可能でしょうか。

Comment: 起動時パラメーターは指定出来なくても、ユーザープロファイルの設定情報を変えられるか試してみては？ こちらの記事がそんな内容を扱っていそうです。[Remotely debug Windows devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/windows) それの日本語版ページはこちら。[Windows デバイスをリモートでデバッグする](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/windows)